# Indie science fiction film. Two siblings (one in a wheelchair) take in a stranger

Tags: story-identification, movie

An adult brother and sister live in the desert and take in a stranger who is on the run. The brother, who is in a wheelchair, dreams of creating a flying machine.

The sister ends up falling in love with the stranger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is  *[Spirits of the Air, Gremlins of the Clouds](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098373/)*.

> When they encounter a wandering stranger named Smith (Norman Boyd), their simple lives become tumultuous as the wheelchair-bound Felix dreams of flying and Betty believes their new arrival to be a demonic presence - the characters all yearning for escape but seemingly do not know how.